# How to compute the mean of three or more location coordinates

Tags: circular-statistics

I have basically three location coordinates viz. (lat1, long1), (lat2, long2) and (lat3, long3). How to calculate the mean of these three points? It`s not like arithmetic mean for euclidean points since these are points on a sphere.

Regards, 
Lesnar

Comment: You can calculate a mean direction on the sphere. A good reference is Mardia & Jupp's Directional Statistics.

Comment: This, and several generalizations, are answered at [GIS.SE], Please [search the site](http://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=spherical+centroid).